# Flash 8: Write predetermined text into a field char by char

Tags: flash, actionscript, text

I have a text field, and what I would like to happen is whenever the user presses a button on their keyboard regardless of the button, some characters are written into the text field. The content of what is to be written is held in a text file, because it's just too large to be stored in a variable.

So, when the user presses a button on the keyboard for the first time, the first character of the .txt file is written into the text field, when the second button is pressed, second character, etc.

I've got the button input down. I just don't quite get text commands down.

I'm currently using Actionscript2.0 and Flash 8.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

AS2, eh?  That takes me back.  Let me see if I can recall enough memory and knowledge to help you out.

Are you sure you can't load the text file into a variable?  Strings can hold a lot of characters.

Anyway, I'm going to assume that the user is not typing into the text field when they press keys on their keyboard.

You can create an event listener to respond to users pressing keys, so that when the user presses any key stuff happens.

```
    var keyListener:Object = new Object()
    keyListener.onKeyDown = function() {
        // Insert code here
        addCharacterToText()
    }
    Key.addListener(keyListener)
```